# How to use Multithreading concept in Spring MVC for subsequent operations

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I would like to send an email and update activity logs after updating profile successfully in my web application. For sending mails and updating activity logs, I would like to use thread so that the profile update response can be sent back to the client immediately and the subsequents operations can be taken care by threads. Please suggest an implementation.

Comment: keep a flag column in profile table. You have to write separate cron job using cron expression. Write a separate logic  in a method and call that method in cron job execute method. That method should perform search using flag,what are the records that function need to be performed. After sending email (and activity log) you can update flag.

Comment: I don't need to necessarily add a flag and moreover, I would like to know the code implementation.

Comment: Ok.When email server crash or application server shutting process. Session will terminate and you can't capture un-processed things with this process.

Comment: Agreed. That way it would make sense to put flag. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to achieve this, the fact that it's a Spring MVC application is almost irrelevant.

If you're using Java 8 then you can simply call upon the executor service to give you a thread from its pool:

```
    String emailAddress = //get email address...
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.submit(() -> {
       emailService.sendNotification(emailAddress); 
    });
```

Pre-Java 8:

```
final String emailAddress = "";
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        emailService.sendNotification(emailAddress);
    }
});
thread.start();
```

If you're creating a more complex application then you should look into possibly using a message queue (ActiveMQ is good).  This allows you more control and visibility and scales well as you add more asynchronous tasks, it also means you won't starve your application server of threads if there are lots of registrations at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a BlockingQueue and implement a producer-consumer model to solve the problem. Your existing program acts as a producer, which adds a token into the BlockingQueue and an executor (which is created out of Executors.newFixedThreadpool) can do all your subsequent operations. You can refer the Javadocs and create your Spring context (as XML or annotations).

Also you can refer [CompletionSerive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html)

Spawning a thread to send and email as and when a profile is saved is not a good idea. Because it might result in too many threads and context switching might cause delay in completion. Hence the suggestion to use fixed thread pool.

A JMS queue can be used. But it looks like an overkill for the given scenario. Hence the suggestion to use BlockingQueue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.